# avoid multiple new tab for same link

Tags: javascript

```
var mywin = null;
var mywin1 = null;
var mywin2 = null;
var mywin3 = null;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
  if (mywin == null || mywin.closed) {
    mywin = window.open('https://google.com');
  } else {
    mywin.focus();
  }
  if (mywin1 == null || mywin1.closed) {
    mywin1 = window.open("https://facebook.com");
  } else {
    mywin1.focus();
  }
  if (mywin2 == null || mywin2.closed) {
    mywin2 = window.open("https://youtube.com");
  } else {
    mywin2.focus();
  }
  if (mywin3 == null || mywin3.closed) {
    mywin3 = window.open("https://gmail.com");
  } else {
    mywin3.focus();
  }
});
```

> this code avoid the duplicate new tab when tab already open but this code work correctly when click but after some time i try to click it will open all tab again pls help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the second argument `name` to the `window.open("http://facebook.com", "fbwin");`

More on window.open can be found here ... http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: i tried but still not working correctly again open all tab duplicate in chrome

Comment: check is there any problem with manifest files this below code is manifest.json :    {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Reviewer",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "This extension will help to open all Require Reviewer link in a single page ",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_title": "Reviewer Tool"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "samplecode.js"
        ],
        "persistent": false
    }
}

Comment: Where are you testing the code? I tried to do an example on codepen and it failed. However when I upload a file to my server it is working in Chrome. http://mindtwitch.com/winopen.html you can view source. The JS code is at the bottom of the html page.

Comment: I tried chrome extension in developer mode in manifest file remove the default icon code

Comment: Are you developing a chrome extension? or is this a webpage?

Comment: I'm developing chrome extension when i clicking the extension icon.it will open 4 new tab On one Click .
2) When I click on same button, If the window is already open it will not open it again

Comment: I would update your question above to indicate that this is for a chrome extension and maybe update the tags as well. I am not a chrome developer but here is one thing I found that might help lead you in the right direction. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows ... Seems that will give you control over creating windows/tabs in your extension.

Comment: Thank u for replaying my all questions,this really  help me lot

Comment: Happy to help out. Good luck with your extension. :)